# How to handle django long task on aws

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

i am beginner in django and aws and i'm trying to run my django app on aws, i have this view that make some process on video and displays a loading template while this process is running to make the user wait, so it takes about 3 min or more depending on the video size, it did work on developpement mode but once on aws, the process get stopped after 2700ms maximum. How could i run such long task on aws ?

My views:

```
######################### Call load template ###############################
def process(request):
    return render(request, 'testgif.html')
######################### Process the video and send notification email to user when process is done ###################################
def getor(request):
    # get video from s3 bucket mounted on ec2 instance
    var = Video.objects.order_by('id').last()
    v = '/mnt/s3/media/videos/' + str(var)
    # process
    subprocess.call("./step1.sh %s" % (str(v)), shell=True)
    #send email notification
    current_site = get_current_site(request)
    user = User.objects.values('username').order_by('id').last()
    us = user['username']
    subject = 'Notification of end of process.'
    message = render_to_string('notify.html', {
        'us':us,
        'domain':current_site.domain,
    })
   eml = User.objects.values('email').order_by('id').last()
   toemail = eml['email']
   email = EmailMessage(subject, message, to=[toemail])
   email.send()
   return render(request, 'endexecut.html')
```

My loading template:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load staticfiles %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
         <div class="jumbotron">
              <div class="row">
                 <center>
                   <p> Please wait, your video is processing ! </p>
                   <img src="{% static "images/loading1.gif" %}" id="image-id" width="600" height="400" />
                 </center>
               </div>
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>
{% endblock %}
{% block javascript %}
<script type="text/javascript">
  $.ajax({
     url: '/wmark/',
     type: 'GET',
     dataType: 'html',
     success: function(result){
             $('#image-id').attr('src', result.image);
             $('.container').html(result);
     },
     error: function(xhr){
            alert(xhr.responseText); //Remove this when all is fine.
     }
  });
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: How is it deployed, just an ec2 instance or are you using elastic beanstalk?

Comment: Yes, i am using elastic beanstalk

Answer (score 1):

So the problem here is that request/response cycle is usually terminated once a response isn't received so what you will need to do is trigger a background task that runs in the background and emails the user when the process is done.

I would recommend something like celery which allows you to start a process and continue the request/response cycle with interruption.

If you want something to keep track while the user waits on the page you will also look into web sockets which can update you on the progress of the 'processing'. But this extra work can be avoided by simply sending an email once celery is done the processing of the video.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, do i have to define two celery tasks; the first for video processing and the other for email notification and call them with delay in my view ?

Comment: @c.ceti that is one way of solving it yes.